# SymPy division doesn't cancel what it can when using symbolic denominator

Tags: python, sympy

I have some code using `sympy.solvers.solve()` that basically leads to the following:

```py
>>> k, u, p, q = sympy.symbols('k u p q')
>>> solution = (k*u + p*u + q)/(k+p)
>>> solution.simplify()
(k*u + p*u + q)/(k + p)
```

Now, my problem is that it is not simplified enough/correctly. It should be giving the following:

```py
q/(k + p) + u
```

From the original equation `q = (k + p)*(m - u)` this is more obvious (when you solve it manually, which my students will be doing).

I have tried many combinations of `sol.simplify()`, `sol.cancel()`, `sol.collect(u)` but I haven't found what can make it work (btw, the `collect` I can't really use, as I won't know beforehand which symbol will have to be collected, unless you can make something that collects *all* the symbols in the solution).

I am working with BookWidgets, which automatically corrects the answers that students give, which is why it's important that I have an output which will match what the students will enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want the expression in quotient/remainder form:

```py
>>> n, d = solution.as_numer_denom()
>>> div(n, d)
(u, q)
>>> _[0] + _[1]/d
q/(k + p) + u
```

But that SymPy function may give unexpected results when the symbol names are changed as described [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23828). Here is an alternative (for which I did not find any existing function in SymPy) that attempts more a synthetic division result:

```py
def sdiv(p, q):
    """return w, r if p = w*q + r else 0, p

    Examples
    ========

    >>> from sympy.abc import x, y
    >>> sdiv(x, x)
    (1, 0)
    >>> sdiv(x, y)
    (0, x)
    >>> sdiv(2*x + 3, x)
    (2, 3)
    >>> a, b=x + 2*y + z, x + y
    >>> sdiv(a, b)
    (1, y + z)
    >>> sdiv(a, -b)
    (-1, y + z)
    >>> sdiv(-a, -b)
    (1, -y - z)
    >>> sdiv(-a, b)
    (-1, -y - z)
    """
    from sympy.core.function import _mexpand
    P, Q = map(lambda i: _mexpand(i, recursive=True), (p, q))
    r, wq = P.as_independent(*Q.free_symbols, as_Add=True)
    # quick exit if no full division possible
    if Q.is_Add and not wq.is_Add:
        return S.Zero, P
    # check multiplicative cancellation
    w, bot = fraction((wq/Q).cancel())
    if bot != 1 and wq.is_Add and Q.is_Add:
        # try maximal additive extraction
        s1 = s2 = 1
        if signsimp(Q, evaluate=False).is_Mul:
            wq = -wq
            r = -r
            Q = -Q
            s1 = -1
        if signsimp(wq, evaluate=False).is_Mul:
            wq = -wq
            s2 = -1
        xa = wq.extract_additively(Q)
        if xa:
            was = wq.as_coefficients_dict()
            now = xa.as_coefficients_dict()
            dif = {k: was[k] - now.get(k, 0) for k in was}
            n = min(was[k]//dif[k] for k in dif)
            dr = wq - n*Q
            w = s2*n
            r = s1*(r + s2*dr)
            assert _mexpand(p - (w*q + r)) == 0
            bot = 1
    return (w, r) if bot == 1 else (S.Zero, p)
```

The more general suggestion from [Davide_sd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2329968/davide-sd) about using `equals` is good if you are only testing the equality of two expressions in different forms.

Comment: This only happens to work for this particular choice of symbols. In general you'd need to do something like `div(n, d, k)`. In that case you might as well just use `solution.apart(k)`.

Comment: Thank you! I guess the `solve` or `simplify` functions don't use this. For curiosity I checked this on _all_ my questions, some of which are not in this form at all, and they all stayed correct. I did notice it took slightly longer, so that's probably why it's not used, but I feel like these cancellations should definitely be done with `simplify`, so I think they should implement it standardly maybe. 

And @OscarBenjamin I only used `div(n, d)` and it worked in all cases (the letters of the symbols are chosen random from the alphabet for each question).

Comment: Actually, I encountered a few questions where it did affect the output. In some cases, a simple `.expand()` would get it back to the desired output, but in others not. For example, with `solution = -c + (h + p)/e`, after following these steps I get `(-c*e + h + p)/e`. Now, unfortunately, `.expand()` also separates the `(h+p)`, which is not simplified (and also won't simplify to what I started with). So I guess I understand why they can't just implement it standardly.

Comment: I think `div` should recognize this easy case: if `d` is a symbol then the `n` should be separated into terms that do and do not have `d` as a factor, cancel `d` out and return that part and the remainder, e.g. `(c, h + p)` for your case.

Comment: I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23828)

Comment: I added a more robust routine to the answer that should handle this quotient/remainder calculation.

Answer (score 1):

First things first:

- there is no "standard" output to a simplification step.
- if the output of a simplification step doesn't suit your need, you might want to manipulate the expression with `simplify`, `expand`, `collect`, ...
- two or more sequences of operations (`simplify`, `expand`, `collect`, ...) might lead to different results, or might lead to the same results. It depends on the expression being manipulated.

Let me show you with your example:

```
k, u, p, q = symbols('k u p q')
solution = (k*u + p*u + q)/(k+p)
# out1: (k*u + p*u + q)/(k + p)

solution = solution.collect(u)
# out2: (q + u*(k + p))/(k + p)

num, den = fraction(solution)
# use the linearity of addition
solution = Add(*[t / den for t in num.args])
# out3: q/(k + p) + u
```

In the above code, `out1, out2, out3` are mathematically equivalent.

Instead of spending time to simplify outputs, I would test for mathematical equivalence with the `equals` method. For example:

```
verified_solution = (k*u + p*u + q)/(k+p)

num, den = fraction(verified_solution)
first_studend_sol = Add(*[t / den for t in num.args])
print(verified_solution.equals(first_studend_sol))
# True

second_student_solution = q/(k + p) + u
print(verified_solution.equals(second_student_solution))
# True

third_student_solution = q/(k + p) + u + 2
print(verified_solution.equals(third_student_solution))
# False
```

Comment: Thank you for some very good tips for sure, it works in some cases. I ended up just `.collect`-ing every variable, which luckily still worked. However, for one problem I get the following solution: `(a*(-d + e) - b)/(d - e)`. Here, `a*(-d+e)/(d-e)` won't simplify out to `-a`. 

As for checking equality: unfortunately that is not an option. I _am_ using Python to create my questions, but I then paste my output (formatted text) into a program called BookWidgets, which is definitely not made for math, so it basically just compares text. (though it can now use latex syntax, so that's a plus)